# click button on website using scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to ask how about (do crawling) clicking next button(change number page of website) (then do crawling more till the end of page number) from [this site](https://n0where.net/)

I've try to combining scrape with selenium,but its still error and says `"line 22
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block"`

I don't know why it happens, i think i code is so well.Anybody can resolve this problem?

**This my source :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from now.items import NowItem
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
name = "nowhere"
allowed_domains = ["n0where.net"]
start_urls = ["https://n0where.net/"]

def parse(self, response):
    for article in response.css('.loop-panel'):
        item = NowItem()
        item['title'] = article.css('.article-title::text').extract_first()
        item['link'] = article.css('.loop-panel>a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        item['body'] ='' .join(article.css('.excerpt p::text').extract()).strip()
        #item['date'] = article.css('[itemprop="datePublished"]::attr(content)').extract_first()
        yield item

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse2(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)

    while True:
        next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/a[8]/span')

        try:
            next.click()

            # get the data and write it to scrapy items
        except:
            break

    self.driver.close()`
```

**This my capture of my program mate :**
[image: capture program]

Comment: your code is underindented, everything after line 5 has to be indented by 4 spaces because that code belongs to your class.

Comment: ah, python having rules about it? -_- i dont know about that, before this i coding using java or c# and both of it dont have rules like that, it seems having so much differently...
btw its all my code its seems okay, can be running..but after i add line 19 and more its error and i dont know why mate (after mozilla driver)...

Comment: yes, indentation in python matters, that's how you define scopes since there are no curly braces etc. Honestly you should do proper indendation in any programming language, curly braces or not...

Comment: here mates, my codes...its seems okay automatically adding 4spaces, but i dont know why when i copy-paste it in here its automatically became left alignt -_-
btw do you have solution about what problem is faced by me?

Comment: see on pict, i reupload my source pict mate..

Comment: huh, just give minus to my populatiry without giving solution?
did you know term of "A tree is known by its fruit." :)

Comment: Sorry, but your question is badly formatted and doesn't even provide a problem to solve. The error already provides you solution which is to indent your code properly. General rule of thumb is - if you want people to help you, you have to make it as easy as possible for them.

Comment: its okay, thanks for suggestion bro :)

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring the syntax and indentation errors you have an issue with your code logic in general.

What you do is create webdriver and never use it. What your spider does here is:

1. Create webdriver object.
2. Schedule a request for every url in `self.start_urls`, in your case it's only one.
3. Download it, make `Response` object and pass it to the `self.parse()`
4. Your parse method seems to find some xpaths and makes some items, so scrapy yields you some items that were found if any
5. Done

Your parse2 was never called and so your selenium webdriver was never used.

Since you are not using scrapy to download anything in this case you can just override `start_requests()`(<- that's where your spider starts) method of your spider to do the whole logic.

Something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nowhere"
    allowed_domains = ["n0where.net"]
    start_url = "https://n0where.net/"

    def start_requests(self):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(self.start_url)
        while True:
            next_url = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                '/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/a[8]/span')
            try:
                # parse the body your webdriver has
                self.parse(driver.page_source)
                # click the button to go to next page 
                next_url.click()
            except:
                break
        driver.close()

    def parse(self, body):
        # create Selector from html string
        sel = Selector(text=body)
        # parse it
        for article in sel.css('.loop-panel'):
            item = dict()
            item['title'] = article.css('.article-title::text').extract_first()
            item['link'] = article.css('.loop-panel>a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            item['body'] = ''.join(article.css('.excerpt p::text').extract()).strip()
            # item['date'] = article.css('[itemprop="datePublished"]::attr(content)').extract_first()
            yield item
```

Comment: thanks mate, i'll try it tomorrow, right now i've to prepared igredients for presentated
i'am newbie on using python, its so different with java or c# ...so the positioning of number on python programming, list code its giving affect to logic coding..

Comment: hey mate its succes, the main problem is firefox v47 it isnt compatible with my selenium version, so i do downgrade firefox,
btw did you know why this error happened "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" what it means mate?
in case, i wanna do scrapping until the last of the page...

Comment: Regarding the error it means what it says right there. Your code is trying to iterate through a `None` Value. My guess it would be this bit `for article in sel.css('.loop-panel')` you need to check whether there are some articles, if there aren't then break the process i.e. `if not sel.css('.loop-panel'): return`

Answer (score 1):

This is a indentation error. Look the lines near the error:

```
    def parse2(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
```

The first of these two lines ends with a colon. So, the second line should be more indented than the first one.

There are two possible fixes, depending on what you want to do. Either add an indentation level to the second one:

```
    def parse2(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
```

Or move the `parse2 function out of the`**init**` function:

```
def parse2(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    # etc.
```

Comment: its seems okay mate after i rewrite that line like your, but why suddenly didnt do creeping and force closed my mozilla firefox, any solution mate?

Comment: @beboy your webdriver closes because it's actually not getting used, check my answer for me info why is that happening.